# Science, where is the difference between law and principle?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, scientific-method, induction, theory

Theories contain laws, definitions, explain and predict aspects of nature.

A law in itself does not explain, but only reflects cause-effect relationships of empirical data (usually in the form of a mathematical equation) that one believes to have recognised in patterns.

But what is the difference between a law and a principle?

For example, is "Archimedes' principle" equivalent to "Archimedes' law"?

Comment: No clear cut definition.

Comment: Maybe a possible "informal" distinction is: a law is usually expressed by a "theorem" of the theory, while a principle is a sort of axiom: the starting points of the theory.

Comment: See Gerald Weinberg's "From broad to narrow" http://ryanbarringtoncox.github.io/notes/an-introduction-to-general-systems-thinking/

Comment: The lines are blurry, but principles are often more general, e.g. the principle of microscopic reversibility is not specific enough to be stated as a law or equation. To make matters even more complicated, scientists also sometimes speak of theorems, e.g. the equipartition theorem, or the maximum power theorem. These seem mostly to be cases where they can be deduced from more basic principles or laws, although again, the lines are blurred.

Comment: See Johnson's surmise in [The Principal Difference Between Laws and Principles of Physics](http://claesjohnson.blogspot.com/2014/05/the-principal-difference-between-laws.html):"*Laws are expressed in quantitative mathematical formulas. Principles are expressed in words. Laws are statements about physical reality (which may or may not be true). Principles express stipulations which are to be respected by physicists... Principles are man-made and need no justification. Laws relate to physical reality and require justification*", etc.

Comment: Principle: Do not kill a human.
Law: Murder is illegal and punishable.

Answer (score 1):

Principles are more general than laws, and are usually not formulated as mathematical equations.

Example:  [The principle of relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_relativity)

> In physics, the principle of relativity is the requirement that the equations describing the laws of physics have the same form in all admissible frames of reference.

> For example, in the framework of special relativity the Maxwell equations have the same form in all inertial frames of reference. In the framework of general relativity the Maxwell equations or the Einstein field equations have the same form in arbitrary frames of reference.

> Several principles of relativity have been successfully applied throughout science, whether implicitly (as in Newtonian mechanics) or explicitly (as in Albert Einstein's special relativity and general relativity).

Thus, Newton laws and Einstein relativity theory obey the principle of relativity (although with different view on time and the constraint on the constancy of the speed of light), Maxwell equations for electromagnetic waves also obey the principle of relativity.

Answer (score 0):

Laws describe fundamental interactions and relations between things that hold with indubitable certainty. Law-like events are most likely to occur and their probability is extremely high. One such example is the laws of classical mechanics that were observed to hold no matter what. Laws can be so basic to have little to no explanations.

Principles are detailed rules/explanations of some phenomena. For instance, principles are required to sufficiently describe the gene theory. Principles typically require more details, because those *can* be provided, as opposed to laws that are more (if not the most) fundamental features of the universe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you clarify how principles differ from theories then?

Comment: @iwab see: https://www.expii.com/t/scientific-principle-definition-examples-10310